# How to convert multiple .png files to .mat files

Tags: matlab, file, png, format-conversion

spatial data (.png)

```
001.png
002.png
003.png
.
.
.
00n.png
```

to

```
001.mat
002.mat
003.mat
.
.
.
00n.mat
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the point/benefit of doing this?

Comment: or to put my question in to context: `png` is a universal format, vs. `mat` you'll have thumbnails and interoperability with other software. Saving a single image in a `mat` file will give you... slightly faster loading into matlab (and that's about it!). Both formats use lossless compression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complementing the answer of EitanT, if you have files which does not have such filename restrictions, such as:

```
file01.png
file02.png
fls1.png
fls2.png
pics001.png
pics002.png
```

You can use `dir` function, which gives you more flexibility. For example:

```
filenames = dir('*.png'); %# get information of all .png files in work dir
n  = numel(filenames);    %# number of .png files

for i = 1:n
    A = imread( filenames(i).name );

    %# gets full path, filename radical and extension
    [fpath radical ext] = fileparts( filenames(i).name ); 

    save([radical '.mat'], 'A');                          
end
```

`fileparts` is a MATLAB function which decomposes the filename in file path, radical and extension. *E.g.*, if I have the file `/home/user/photo.png`, this function will return:

```
fpath   = /home/user
radical = photo
ext     = .png
```

**File format error**

OP got the following error:

> ??? Error using ==> imread at 387 Unable to determine the file format. Error in ==> PNG2MATFiles at 5 A = imread( filenames(i).name );

I've download his original *.png images and tested them with `file` linux command. My output:

> FY2E_2011_09_01_00_01_ir1_proj.png: Matlab v5 mat-file (little endian)
>   version 0x0100 FY2E_2011_09_01_01_01_ir1_proj.png: Matlab v5 mat-file
>   (little endian) version 0x0100 FY2E_2011_09_01_02_01_ir1_proj.png:
>   Matlab v5 mat-file (little endian) version 0x0100
>   FY2E_2011_09_01_03_01_ir1_proj.png: Matlab v5 mat-file (little endian)
>   version 0x0100 FY2E_2011_09_01_04_01_ir1_proj.png: Matlab v5 mat-file
>   (little endian) version 0x0100 FY2E_2011_09_01_05_01_ir1_proj.png:
>   Matlab v5 mat-file (little endian) version 0x0100
>   FY2E_2011_09_01_06_01_ir1_proj.png: Matlab v5 mat-file (little endian)
>   version 0x0100 FY2E_2011_09_01_07_01_ir1_proj.png: Matlab v5 mat-file
>   (little endian) version 0x0100 FY2E_2011_09_01_08_01_ir1_proj.png:
>   Matlab v5 mat-file (little endian) version 0x0100
>   FY2E_2011_09_01_09_01_ir1_proj.png: Matlab v5 mat-file (little endian)
>   version 0x0100 FY2E_2011_09_01_10_01_ir1_proj.png: Matlab v5 mat-file
>   (little endian) version 0x0100

`imread` can't open these files as `'png'` because they are already stored as `.mat`.

Comment: ??? Error using ==> imread at 387
Unable to determine the file format.

Error in ==> PNG2MATFiles at 5
    A = imread( filenames(i).name );

how it error???

Comment: Try `A = imread(filenames(i).name, 'png')`

Comment: Are all the images in the working directory .png? Can you load some of them with `A = imread('001.png','png');`?

Comment: Also, try the following command in MATLAB: `filenames = dir('*.png')` and then print the files obtained with `filenames.name`. Are they the only files you want to load?

Comment: In Folder have only .png and can printf name with filenames.naame

Comment: filenames = dir('*.png');

n=numel(filenames);
fprintf('number of .png %i files \n',n);

for i=1:n
    fprintf('number %i name : %s \n', i,filenames(i).name);
end

Comment: download my data : https://www.box.com/s/6d5d6b4199cfae3673ed

Comment: @VictorHugo try again or click here https://www.box.com/s/6d5d6b4199cfae3673ed

Comment: thanks, i think that it have problem from move file

Comment: @Sadiq you're welcome! :-) Hope everything is working fine now

Comment: @VictorHugo , thanks for your attention ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i = 1:n
    A = imread(['00', num2str(i), '.png'], 'png');  %# Read PNG file
    save(['00', num2str(i), '.mat'], 'A');          %# Store data to MAT file
end
```